# Complex Query in CodeIgniter Active Record or Ignited Datatables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datatables

Following is the query to take all records from page table and respective access_level from role_page_access table, join together by page.id for a given roleid. $roleid is the parameter to this method.

```
$query = 'select p.*,t.access_level from page p '.
    'left join (SELECT p.id,rpa.role_id,rpa.access_level FROM page p '.
    'left join role_page_access rpa on rpa.page_id = p.id '.
    'where rpa.role_id = ' . $roleid . ') as t on p.id = t.id';
```

Actually, I need to use this query for ignited datatables. But at least if I can convert this to active record, that will be very helpful.

Is there a way to just specify regular query in active records?
Otherwise how to convert this to active records?

UPDATE:
page table has pages and role_page_access table has mapping between userrole and page with an integer field "access_level" to specify have access or not. If there are no mapping also considered as no access.

I want all the records from page and matching access_level from role_page_access by pageid and given role. So there will be null access_level if no matching records found in mapping table.

I have to use this in `$this->db` or `$this->datatables`.

Comment: $query = $this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE'); you can also do this using active record

Comment: Thanks Sam, this works. I will keep your answer as alternative solution, if I can find active record solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with activerecord like this:

```
$this->-db->select('page.*,role_page_Access.access_level');
$this->db->from('page');
$this->db->join('role_page_access', 'role_page_access.page_id = page.id', 'left outer');
$this->db->where('role_page_access.role_id', $role_id);

$query = $this->db->get();

foreach($query->result() as $row) {
    if(empty($row->access_level)) {
        echo 'Role does not have access';
    } else {
        echo 'Role has access';
    }
}
```

That will join the `page` table records with the `role_page_access` table records by the `page.id` field if it matches, filtered by the `role_id` you pass along.

You can even do method chaining if you have a supported PHP version, check the reference [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select).

**Update**

If you still want to retrieve page records even if that `role_id` does not have access you just have to set the join as left outer:

```
$this->db->join('role_page_access', 'role_page_access.page_id', 'left outer');
```

That'll give ALL pages records, even if they don't match a role on `role_page_access` and the resultset object will have a `NULL` value on `role_page_access`. I updated the original code to show you an example.

**Update 2**
If you want to filter by `role_id` but still have the unmatched records:

```
$this->db->where('role_page_access.role_id', $role_id);
$this->db->or_where('role_page_access.role_id', NULL);
```

But you will have to filter them by the `access_level` to check if is `NULL` cause if it is, it means that there was no matching page for the `page_id` and the `role_id` (that you passed as param) combination:

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. However, this omits the page records if there is no marching records in the mapping tables. See my update in question. Can you modify your answer little.

Comment: No buddy, still it returns the same. i.e, no null records from the role_page_access table. :(

Comment: Well of course it will not return the null values as long as you have them filtered by role_id... if what you want to get them both you need to add an or... see my updated response

Comment: Thanks for the update 2. It takes if any null value records. In my case, there is no record at all. So still the same result. For now, I'm stick to Sam's suggestion.